# How To Connect Electrodes to Transimpedance Amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, connector, current-measurement, wiring, electrode

I wrote a post earlier last week asking the same question, but I have better information now. I have a microfluidic cell with silver electrodes with 1mm diameter and about an inch long. I need to connect them to gold connectors on a transimpedance amplifier (and no, unfortunately the electrodes and connectors are not the same distance apart). The current measured from them will be in the pico/nano ampere range. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

[image: Transimpedance amplifier with gold connectors]
[image: Microfluidic cell]

Comment: @ocrdu that was my first question that I edited to include better images but I wasn't getting any responses after editing so I reposted it here

Comment: Posting a duplicate question is not the right way to get attention. You can either bring it up in [chat] to try to bring it to the attention of others, or post a bounty (which will require you to earn some reputation and then cash it in) -- see the [help] for more details. I suggest you delete this question.

Comment: @Null I see -- it won't let me delete it but I'll keep in mind the etiquette of Stack Exchange for future posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

crocodile clips...
or soldering wires to the base or underside of the gold terminals, this is a circuit board like any other and can be bodged the same way

Ideally the length of wire is as short as possible, but if you need more than 50cm you can use shielded/coaxial cable (e.g. cutting up a good quality USB cable)

Comment: So crocodile clips to the electrodes and gold terminals will work fine for the small current as long as the length is rather small? And thank you!